# How to read XLS file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, xls

I want to read xls file in node js using the code below.

```
    const xlsxFile = require('read-excel-file/node');
    const xlsx = require('xlsx');
    const workbook = xlsx.readFile('POTemplate.xls');
    const sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
    var data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
    var data5 = JSON.stringify(data[6]);
    console.log(data5);
```

by using this code how can we get each cell value row-wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over array of objects

Example

```
data.forEach(el => console.table(el))
```